# strings: finding segments using slice

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I'm currently learning JS with the book "A smarter way to learn JS" but I m stuck at chapter 23.

I'm searching a way to replace banned characters from a text, which the user can enter with prompt, through the following code:

```
function trouve() {

var text = prompt("texte");
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text.slice(i, i+12) === "x" ) {
    text = text.slice(0, i) + "y" + text.slice(i + 12);
    alert(text);
  }
}
}
```

The problem is, whatever comes before the "x" appears, but if I put text after, it no longer works.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: can you specify the input and expected output?

Comment: Why not just use `replace()` native method ? `.replace('x', 'y')`

Answer (score 0):

As @johannchopin mentioned in the comments, you would be better off with using the native .replace method of JavaScript.

Here is a small example to replace all occurrences of the alphabet 'a'.

```
var message = "A quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog";

const newMessage = message.replace(/a/ig, '*');

console.log(newMessage);
```

Output

```
* quick brown fox jumps over * l*zy dog
```

/ig - represents ignore case (i), search globally (g)